# Number of days until next birthday

Tags: powershell, date, object, calculation

My problem is to do a calculation of when your next birthday is in days.
I already did an input and a calculation, but the format of the date is wrong.

I want my program to calculate your next Birthday in days with this format: `DD.MM.YYYY` and without decimals. Also when I type in something like "hello" it shouldn't crash but give me an error that it is not a valid date.

```
#Clearing
Clear-Host

#Liste von Variabeln
$geburtstag
$datumvonheute
$zeitbisgeburtstag

#initialisieren von Variabeln
$geburtstag = Get-Date 
$datumvonheute = Get-Date
$zeitbisgeburtstag = ""

function ParseDate([string]$datumvonheute)
{
    try{
        $result = 0
        if (!([DateTime]::TryParse($datumvonheute, [ref]$result)))
        {
            throw "Es wurde ein falsches Datum eingegeben! $geburtstag"
        }
        $isok = $true
        $geburtstag.ToDateTime($geburtstag)

    } catch {
        $result
        Write-Host "Falsche Eingabe!"
        $isok = $false
    }
}
do{
    $geburtstag = Read-Host "Bitte geben Sie ihren nächsten Geburtsdatum ein [dd.mm.yyyy]"
    ParseDate($geburtstag)
} until($isok = $true)

$FromDate  =[DateTime] $datumvonheute
$ToDate    =[DateTime] $geburtstag

($ToDate - $FromDate).TotalDays
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format date might be wrong because of many reasons, but I am assuming that it is because the culture is not the same: on your laptop it could be en-US culture (MM/dd/yyyy), while the date format you are entering is de-de culture (dd/MM/yyyy).

You could define the culture at the beginning and than use it to properly set per your needs.

```
$cultureInfo = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo('de-de')
```

Your problem is here:

```
$geburtstag.ToDateTime($geburtstag)
```

You need to parse it to get the correct date:

```
$geburtstag = [datetime]::Parse($datumvonheute,$cultureInfo)
```

And I would calculate `$fromDate - $toDate` , not vice versa

```
#Clearing
Clear-Host
$cultureInfo = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo('de-de')
#Liste von Variabeln
$geburtstag
$datumvonheute
$zeitbisgeburtstag

#initialisieren von Variabeln
$geburtstag = Get-Date 
$datumvonheute = Get-Date
$zeitbisgeburtstag = ""

function ParseDate([string]$datumvonheute)
{
    try{
        $result = 0
        if (!([DateTime]::TryParse($datumvonheute, [ref]$result)))
        {
            throw "Es wurde ein falsches Datum eingegeben! $geburtstag"
        }
        $isok = $true
        #$geburtstag.ToDateTime($geburtstag)
        $geburtstag = [datetime]::Parse($datumvonheute,$cultureInfo)

    } catch {
        $result
        Write-Host "Falsche Eingabe!"
        $isok = $false
    }
}
do{
    $geburtstag = Read-Host "Bitte geben Sie ihren nächsten Geburtsdatum ein [dd.mm.yyyy]"
    ParseDate($geburtstag)
} until($isok = $true)

$FromDate  =[DateTime] $datumvonheute
$ToDate    =[DateTime] $geburtstag

$totaldays = ($FromDate - $ToDate).Days

Write-Output "Total Days: $totaldays"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I see where I did my mistakes. The format of the date is still wrong tough I formatted it with your solution and another one. Also when I input something thats not in the same format as it says it gives me an error. Isn't the first function (ParseDate) to catch these wrong inputs?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for a late reply. You are getting an error message from the last three lines of code in your script. Since you are not entering [datetime], it cannot convert other types to datetime and therefore it throws you an error. Run your script again, and check at what line you receive the error in red. Try/Catch block is giving you a regular output, the one you wrapped it in 'throw' and also in Write-Host